# ffmpeg: stills converted to video are turned to greyscale; started recently, is inconsistent

Tags: ffmpeg, video, colors, animation

Looping images to create animations. Until a few days ago, zero problems. Recently one video came out greyscale. Next video, using a copy of the same script with different, but very similar, images, it works fine.

Some videos are coming out greyscale. Some look as expected.

Mac Mini Monterey. FFmpeg v6.0

In the terminal, running

`sh imgvid.sh filename`

````
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -t 3.0 -i $100.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.0 -i $101.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.0 -i $102.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.0 -i $103.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.0 -i $104.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.0 -i $105.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.0 -i $106.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.0 -i $107.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.0 -i $108.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.0 -i $109.jpg -filter_complex " 
    [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset= 1[f1]; 
    [f1][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=2[f2]; 
    [f2][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=3[f3]; 
    [f3][4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=4[f4]; 
    [f4][5]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=5[f5]; 
    [f5][6]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=6[f6]; 
    [f6][7]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=7[f7]; 
    [f7][8]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=8[f8]; 
    [f8][9]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=9,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -movflags +faststart -r 25 $1.mp4```
````

Answer (score 0):

turns out if ANY images are grayscale, the whole video is grayscale. removed a few stray grayscale images (not sure why my creation process produced those) and all is well. Imagemagick's identify tool is a quick way to verify vast swaths of files for gray vs color.